# How track json request sent to Elasticsearch via elastic4s client?

Tags: json, scala, http, elasticsearch, elastic4s

Say that I use such code:

```
ElasticClient client = ...
client.execute{search in "places"->"cities" query "paris" start 5 limit 10}
```

How to see what json request was been sent to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Elastic4s 1.6.2 you can use the [show typeclass](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s#json-output) on a number of requests to get the JSON equivilent.

It's pretty straightforward.

```
val req = search in "index" / "type" query "kate bush"
logger.debug(s"Search request ${req.show}")
```

The `.show` method will render JSON output. It works on most of the request types.

In Elastic4s 5.2.0+, you use the `show` method on the client.

```
val req = search("index" / "type").query("kate bush")
client.show(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find build-in feature to track every request via elastic4s client, but there is a `_builder` variable in elastic4s which you can use to print request before execute it:

```
println(search in "places"->"cities" query "paris" start 5 limit 10 _builder) toString

{
  "from" : 5,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "paris"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for every request type. Version 1.6 will have a feature to log all queries (or most of them). The reason is that the java client doesn't turn things into json, but the other way around. The REST interface turns json into java calls internally.

Comment: Could you please provide example of non-working request?

Comment: I can't remember but some of the less common ones don't output json (or at least they didn't when I first started elastic4s 2 years ago. Maybe they all do now). I'm going to add some logging to expose these anyway.

Comment: UpdateDsl is an example of one that you can't simply call toString on.