# Logging elastic4s client

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

looking at this example

```
client.execute{search in "places"->"cities" query "paris" start 5 limit 10}
```

is there an option to hook logging to client.execute to log all operations made by the client (index, search etc') ?

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864841/how-track-json-request-sent-to-elasticsearch-via-elastic4s-client) but I do not want to do something like :

```
val req = search in "index" / "type" query "kate bush"
logger.debug(s"Search request ${req.show}")
```

I want the client to log all base on the logging level

Comment: If you enable the DEBUG level in your logging configuration then you'll see some more output about whats' going on internally.

Comment: @Val thanks, it is enabled but I do not see any elastic4s output

Comment: How did you enable it?

Comment: @Val in my build sbt file 
```logLevel in run := Level.Debug```

Comment: @Val also tried adding this 
```import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory
ESLoggerFactory.getRootLogger.setLevel("debug")```
But didn't really help

Comment: Elastic4s doesn't do much logging, but version 5.2.0 does a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own ElasticClient, with overriding execute functionality

```
object MyElasticClientFactory {
     def fromClient(client: Client): ElasticClient = new ElasticClient {
     def close(): Unit = client.close()
     def java: Client = client

     override def execute[T, R, Q](request: T)(implicit executable: Executable[T, R, Q]): Future[Q] = {
         // TODO your logging here
         super.execute(request)
     }

}
```

Take a look at TcpClient for reference https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/9a4074b6ff5616b648801352b4c3629cd0fc9020/elastic4s-tcp/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/TcpClient.scala